# DualBOOT windows 8 and VHDX

Tags: windows-8, bootloader, uefi

I have Windows 8.1 as main OS in UEFI environment and I wanted to have another Windows 8.1 as a VHDX.

I used EasyBCD to add entry for the VHDX but, it didn't boot the VHDX and the boot menu was without GUI.

I tried using BCDEdit Command-Line and added VHDX boot successfully with GUI but I noticed that my Windows 8.1 load first then, it gives me the boot menu meaning when I chose Windows 8.1 it gives me the longing screen IMMEDIATELY and when I chose VHDX it reboots and load the VHDX.

What I need is to go straight to VHDX without booting the main Windows 8.1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the partition where you placed your VHDX is encrypted (bitlocker?).
Create a another partition, put your VHDX there, update the path in boot menu and try again.